# Double recursion using MIPS

Tags: recursion, mips

I am trying to implement double recursion for the function `f(n) = 2f(n-1) + 3f(n-2) + 1`.  I was able to figure out singular recursion and implement the `2f(n-1) + 1` part of it, but I can't figure out how to implement the second part.  Here is my working code for the singular recursion:

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the value for the recursive function f(n) = 2f(n-1)+3f(n-2)+1:  "
prompt2: .asciiz "Result: "
numberEntered: .word 0
answer: .word 0

.text

main:
#Ask for the value
li $v0 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

#enter value
li $v0, 5
syscall

sw $v0, numberEntered  #stores the number

# call the function
lw $a0, numberEntered
jal function
sw $v0, answer

#Print out the result
li $v0 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

lw $a0, answer
li $v0, 1
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

.globl function
function:
subu $sp, $sp, 8
sw $ra, ($sp)
sw $s0, 4($sp)

#base case
li $v0, 1
beq $a0, $zero, done

#calling f(n-1)
move $s0, $a0
sub $a0, $a0, 1
jal function

#calculations occur here
mul $v0, $v0, 2
addi $v0, $v0, 1

done:

lw $ra, ($sp)
lw $s0, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8

jr $ra  #returns
```

I tried loading the address of the next part down the stack in the calculation part of it, but I couldn't figure out the implementation to get it to work.  Do I have to "wind up" the stack twice?  Once how it is currently and once in the calculation section?  I can't figure it out, and any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty good effort.

To answer your question: you can simply establish a stack frame at `function` entry and restore from it at the end.

I did have to repurpose `$s0` slightly to store an intermediate value and add it to the stored values in the stack frame (i.e. stack frame is now 3 words instead of 2).

Anyway, here's the corrected code. I've tried to annotate it a bit (*IMO, in asm, there's no such thing as "too many comments"*) [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
prompt1:    .asciiz     "Enter the value for the recursive function f(n) = 2f(n-1)+3f(n-2)+1:  "
prompt2:    .asciiz     "Result: "
numberEntered:  .word   0
answer:     .word       0

    .text

main:
    # Ask for the value
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt1
    syscall

    # enter value
    li      $v0,5
    syscall

    sw      $v0,numberEntered       # stores the number

    # call the function
    lw      $a0,numberEntered
    jal     function
    sw      $v0,answer

    # Print out the result
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt2
    syscall

    lw      $a0,answer
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

    .globl  function

# function -- calculation
# v0 -- return value
# a0 -- current n value
# s0 -- intermediate result
function:
    subi    $sp,$sp,12              # establish our stack frame

    sw      $ra,8($sp)              # save return address
    sw      $a0,4($sp)              # save n
    sw      $s0,0($sp)              # save intermediate result

    # base case
    # NOTE: with the addition of n-2, the "beq" was insufficient
    li      $v0,1
    ble     $a0,$zero,done

    # calling f(n-1)
    sub     $a0,$a0,1               # get n-1
    jal     function

    # NOTE: these could be combined into a single instruction
    mul     $v0,$v0,2               # get 2f(n-1)
    move    $s0,$v0                 # save it

    # calling f(n-2)
    sub     $a0,$a0,1               # get n-2
    jal     function

    mul     $v0,$v0,3               # get 3f(n-2)

    # get 2f(n-1) + 3f(n-2) + 1
    add     $v0,$s0,$v0
    add     $v0,$v0,1

done:
    lw      $ra,8($sp)              # restore return address
    lw      $a0,4($sp)              # restore n
    lw      $s0,0($sp)              # restore intermediate result

    addi    $sp,$sp,12              # pop stack frame

    jr      $ra                     # returns
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> This solution is way simpler than I thought it would be.

That may be because of the way a stack frame is done in asm [or C].

Consider a modern C program:

```
int
whatever(int n)
{
    int x;

    // point A
    x = other(1);

    // do lots more stuff ...

    {
        // point B
        int y = other(2);

        // do lots more stuff ...

        // point C
        n *= (x + y);
    }

    // do lots more stuff ...

    n += ...;

    return n;
}
```

The C compiler will establish a stack frame upon entry to `whatever` that will reserve *space* for `x` *and* `y` even though `y` is only *set* much later. Most C programmers don't realize this.

In interpreted languages (e.g. `java`, `python`, etc.) space for `y` isn't reserved *until* the code at `point B` is *executed*. And, they will [usually] deallocate it when `y` goes "out of scope" [after `point C`].

Most C programmers *think* that having a scoped declaration [like `y`] saves on stack space. (i.e.) In the scoped block, the compiler would increase the stack frame size to accomodate `y` and shrink it again when `y` is no longer needed.

This is simply *not* correct. The C compiler will set up the stack frame and reserve space for *all* function scoped variables even if they're declared late in the function or inside an inner scope [like `y`].

This is just what we did in your `function`. This is true even though we didn't need/utilize the stack space [at offset 0] for `$s0` until the middle of the function.

So, I'm guessing that your experiences with other languages that *do* reserve space dynamically [effectively] or the common wisdom about C may have led you to a more complex model of what you thought was required. Hence your original question: *Do I have to "wind up" the stack twice?*

---

I should also mention that the calling convention of `function` is *not* ABI conforming. This is *perfectly* fine if it's self contained (i.e. does not call anything else). That is, in asm, for "leaf" functions, we can define whatever we wish.

The reason is that `$a0` call be modified/trashed by *callee*. We saved/restored it from the stack, but calling another function might mess things up. The remedy would simply be to use another register to preserve the value [or save/restore to an extra place in the stack frame], so a bit more work if `function` ends up calling something else.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This solution is way simpler than I thought it would be.

Comment: You're welcome! After thinking about your original question a bit more [re. the 2nd stack], I've added more explanation about the model for a stack frame. I've also added something about the ABI

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now, thanks for everything!  You went above and beyond what I asked.

Comment: I discovered a small error in your code.  On the line under the comment #get 2f(n-1) + 3f(n-2) + 1 it should be add $v0, $s0, $v0 followed by add $v0, $v0, 1.  You used $s0 to keep track of a value but ignored it in the calculation at the end.  I also introduced a secondary base case and got the whole thing working properly.  Is there some place I should post the code?

Comment: You're absolutely right--I missed that. I'll edit my code for posterity. You can edit the question and add it there. But, in general, here, it is _perfectly_ acceptable for you to provide an answer to your own question. Most OPs don't bother. But, it's usually done if there are no answers and OP solves the problem on his/her own. Or, if there are multiple incomplete answers (e.g. 4 answers that solve only 25% each) that, when combined, give OP the answer [possibly with some additional code by OP]. For minor tweaks a comment to responder [which he fixes] is usually the way.