# Find the maximum sum leaf to root in assembly mips with the stack pointer (Mars 4.5)

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have a question about the maximum sum leaf to root in assembly mips code. I use MARS 4,5 assembler. I have this tree value:

```
.data
root: .word 7, n01, n02
n01: .word -4, n03, n04
n02: .word 5, n05, n06
n03: .word 5, n07, n08
n04: .word 2, 0, n09
n05: .word 13, 0, 0
n06: .word -15, n10, n11
n07: .word 1, 0, 0
n08: .word 0, n12, n13
n09: .word 27, 0, 0
n10: .word 23, n14, 0
n11: .word 31, 0, n15
n12: .word -8, 0, 0
n13: .word 12, 0, 0
n14: .word 2, 0, 0
n15: .word 2, 0, 0
```

The first element is a value of node, the second is the left subtree and the third is the right subtree. How can i write the ricorsion with Stack Pointer ($SP) for this problem? thanks so much.

C Code:

```
int maxSumPath (struct node *root) {
if (!root ) return 0;
if(!root.left && !root.right) return root.value;
return max(root.value+maxSumPath(root.left) ,root.value+maxSumPath(root.right)); }
```

[Image Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHmIR.png)
I solved my problem and this is my solution:

```
.text
main:
    la $a0, root #root's address
    jal sum
    move $a0, $v0 #out of the sum
    li $v0, 1 #command to output
    syscall
    li $v0, 10 #exit();
    syscall
sum:
    bnez $a0, sumric #IF(nodo != null) start the recursion
    li $v0, 0 #else right's sum
    jr $ra
sumric:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -12 #allocate space in the stack pointer
    sw $ra, 0($sp) #save ra
    sw $a0, 4($sp) #save node's address
    lw $a0, 4($a0) #load left subtree node's address
    jal sum
    sw $v0, 8($sp) #save the max sum
    lw $a0, 4($sp) #save node's address
    lw $a0, 8($a0) #load right subtree node's address
    jal sum
    lw $t0, 8($sp) #load left subtree's sum
    bge $v0, $t0, maxsumsx #IF(right subtree's sum > left subtree's sum) go to maxsumsx 
    move $v0, $t0 #else overwrite (change) the max sum
maxsumsx:
    lw $t8, 4($sp) #load node's address
    lw $t3, 0($t8) #load node's value
    bne $t8, 0, maxsumdx #IF(right node's address != null) go to calculate right subtree's sum
    addu $t0, $t0, $t3 #else update left sum
    j turnUP
maxsumdx:
    addu $v0, $v0, $t3 #update right sum
    j turnUP
turnUP:
    lw $ra, 0($sp) #update $ra's value in the stack
    addiu $sp, $sp, 12 #deallocate space in the stack pointer
    jr $ra #return back in recursion
```

Comment: Can you write pseudocode or C code for it? Or a flowchart?

Comment: int maxSumPath (struct node *root)

{if (!root ) return 0;
if(!root.left && !root.right) return root.value;
return max(root.value+maxSumPath(root.left)
,root.value+maxSumPath(root.right));
}

Comment: That's not the best code for asm, but anyway, can you translate that to asm? If not, where do you get stuck?

Comment: My problem is the use of the stack pointer for the recursion. C code I posted is an example to explain my problem. i don't know how to use the stack pointer to calculate the maximum sum leaf to root. I just started to program in assembly and I don't know how to translate this code in mips assembly

Comment: You use the stack pointer to allocate local variables. Due to recursion you will at least need to save `$ra`. Do you know how to do that? If not look at some recursion examples here on SO.

Comment: Here are some answers I've given for MIPS recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593184/double-recursion-using-mips/35594593#35594593 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311405/mips-help-recursive-functions/37312363#37312363 BTW, it would make your question better and more complete if you edited it and put the C code from your comment into it in a code block

Comment: I solved my problem, i edit the solution. Thank you so much.