# A * star algorithm in mips assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips, path-finding

so I am trying to use the A * algorithm. I tried to follow the pseudocodes I could find to the best of my ability but I sense that I am repeating something and that I am missing some crucial code to link everything together (aside from drawpixel and squareroot). Can you guys please look over my code and let me know what's wrong? I intended the code to guide a pixel to move from one point to the next but the pixel is not moving. The code here is a cut out of the A star part. I have tried debugging but not seeing what's wrong. I am a newbie please help me out.

```
#A star algorithm attempt
.data
pixelcolour: .word 0xFFFFFF00
twenty: .word 20
linkedlist: .word 0:400

.text
main: 
lw $s1, pixelcolour
li $t2, 100 # object x location
li $t3, 60 # object y location
li $t4, 20 # target x location
li $t5, 300 # target y location

jal callfunc # this creates a grid

euclidean:
sub $s2, $t2, $t4
sub $s3, $t3, $t5
mul $s2, $s2, $s2
mul $s3, $s3, $s3
jal squareroot

#square root aka heuristic stored in t6
#code for square root not included here

move $s3, $t6

up:
subi $t3, $t3, 1 # move up by 1
jal calupcost

calupcost:
 jal euclidean
# add 20 to h
# heuristic stored in t6 and t7
lw $t8, twenty
add $t6, $t6, $t8 # g + h
li $t8, 0
lw $t8, twenty
add $t7, $t7, $t8
add $t7, $t7, $t6 # add the f's for x and y locations

down:
addi $t3, $t3, 1 # move x down
jal caldowncost

caldowncost:
jal euclidean
lw $t1, twenty
add $t6, $t6, $t1 # g +h
li $t1, 0
lw $t1, twenty
add $t7, $t7, $t1 # 20 + h(y)
# add the f's together
add $t1, $t7, $t6

east: 
# to move east add 1 to x location
addi $t2, $t2, 1
jal caleastcost

caleastcost:
jal euclidean
# add 20 to h
lw $t1, twenty
add $t6, $t6, $t1
lw $t1, twenty
add $t7, $t7, $t1
#add the 2 f's
add $t6, $t6, $t7

west:
subi $t2, $t2, 1
jal calwestcost

calwestcost:
lw $t1, twenty
add $t6, $t6, $t1
lw $t1, twenty
add $t7, $t7, $t1
# add the 2 f's
add $t0, $t6, $t7

jal queue

if_a_less_than_b:
jal up
jal down
blt $t7, $t1, a_less_than_b
bgt $t7, $t1, b_less_than_a

b_less_than_a:
jal east
blt $t1, $t6, b_less_than_c
bgt $t1, $t6, c_less_than_b

a_less_than_b:
jal east
blt $t7, $t6, a_less_than_c
bgt $t7,$t6, c_less_than_b

b_less_than_c:
jal west
blt $t1, $t0, useb # if b is less than d
bgt $t1, $t0, d_is_the_least # if b greater than d, d is least

c_less_than_b:
jal west
blt $t6, $t0, usec # if c is less than d
bgt $t6, $t0, d_is_the_least # if c is greater than d, the d is #the least

a_less_than_c:
jal west 
blt $t7, $t0, usea # if a is less than d
bgt $t7, $t0, d_is_the_least # if a is greater than d, d is the #least
# same as c_less_than_b

usec:
move $t3, $t3
addi $t2, $t2, 1
jal drawpixel

useb:
addi $t3, $t3, 1
move $t2, $t2
jal drawpixel

d_is_the_least:
subi $t2, $t2, 1
move $t3, $t3
jal drawpixel

usea:
subi $t3, $t3, 1
move $t2, $t2
jal drawpixel

continueuntilx:
bgt $t2, 300, continueuntily # if x is greater than 300 ...
bne $t2, 300, if_a_less_than_b

continueuntily:
bgt $t3, 30, pause
bne $t3, 30, if_a_less_than_b

pause:
li $t4, 30
li $t5, 300
jal drawpixel

updatedistance:




queue:

lw $a0, linkedlist
li $a1, 0 # value
jal loop
loop: 
beq $a1, $a0, endit
sll $a0, $a0, 4 # offset 
lw $a1, 0($a0)
addi $a1, $a1,1
jal if_a_less_than_b
j loop

endit:
li $v0, 10
syscall


callfunc:
#creates the graph
lw $a3, linkedlist
move $t9, $zero # counter
addi $a3, $a3, -1
sll $a3, $a3, 2
sw $t9, linkedlist($a3)
addi $t9, $t9, 1
beq $t9, 20, endit
#let's say a0 is x and a1 is y
bne $a0, 0, callfunct
addi $s6, $s6, 1 # row counter
callfunct:
bne $a1, 0, callfunc
addi $s7, $s7, 1 # column counter
bne $s7, 20, endit
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I did but not seeing what's wrong. Does this code look like how the A star algorithm should be implemented

Comment: We don't debug code for you. No do we read through a wall code to try and GUESS what the problem might be. You need to explain HOW this code isn't working properly.

Comment: @MarcB I have already tried debugging the code. The code is simply not making a pixel move towards a target location. The drawpixel code is not included in the code posted here however but the drawpixel code works.

Comment: You're having a given function call another that calls another without saving `$ra`. You have `jal euclidean` that does `jal squareroot` See my answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593184/double-recursion-using-mips/35594593#35594593 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311405/mips-help-recursive-functions/37312363#37312363 But, you may also be misusing `jal` as a substitute for `j` for some invocations

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks Craig :) I do realize I constantly mix j and jal. $ra oh yes I did leave that stuff out. Thanks a lot, I'll use your answers to help me make corrections